# passing values from one function to another function in different file using javascript

Tags: javascript

UserList.cshtml

```
`<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '.View', function () { 
showDetail($(this), '/Admin/User/'); });    
</script>`
```

logical.js

```
`function showDetails(soid){
      var soid="1234";
      return soid;
}`
```

User.cshtml

```
`<div class="InlineButton" style="width: 30px; margin-top: 4px;" 
onclick="savePassword(soid)">Save</div>
<script>
function savePassword(soid){
console.log(soid);
}
</script>`
```

So it's just bits and pieces from the whole code. I am in need of some help to pass the soid from showDetails() in logical.js to User.cshtml.

Comment: Do you really have backticks in your files as you've shown?

Comment: To pass data between different HTML pages you need to use cookies or localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "UserList.cshtml" is being displayed and the user clicks on an element with the `.View` class, the anonymous function that calls `showDetail($(this)` will be invoked. `showDetail()` returns `soid` and you are not capturing that return value in "UserList.cshtml", so the first thing you need to do is modify "UserList.cshtml" to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '.View', function () { 
   // Call showDetail() and store the return value in localStorage:
   localStorage.setItem("showDetailResults", showDetail($(this), '/Admin/User/')); 
});
```

Then, in any other page where you need that value (i.e. "User.cshtm"), you'd have the following line after you are sure that there is a value to get out of `localStorage`:

```
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("showDetailResults");
```